# Touchpad disappeared 2 days after I started using usb mouse

Tags: udev, mouse, touchpad, synaptic

Recently I bought a usb mouse for my laptop. It works fine, but today the inbuilt touchpad of the laptop stopped working. It was working in the morning but a couple hours later I noticed that it wasn't working anymore, and `synclient -l` prints "Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?". What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$ xinput
```

This command should print all input devices.

If it doesn’t then run:

```
$ apt-get install xinput
```

And try again.

If you find touchpad then use:

```
$ xinput enable <id of touchpad>
```